# How to re-route the GET resource to return the EDIT view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My question is fairly simple, in an app I'm building, there is no need to **show** a user's account as a separate action from **editing** a user's account.  That is, instead of

```
URL            | HTTP Verb  | Action
============================================
/account/new   | GET        | new
/account/edit  | GET        | edit
/account       | POST       | update
/account       | PUT        | create
```

I'm looking more for:

```
URL            | HTTP Verb  | Action
============================================
/account/new   | GET        | new
/account       | GET        | edit
/account       | PUT        | update
/account       | POST       | create
```

Right now, I have this in my routes file:

```
map.resource :account, :controller => "users", :except => [:show, :destroy]
```

which gets me very close, but how can I reroute the GET at the root level to give me the `edit` action instead of having to specify `/edit` in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
map.connect '/account', :controller => "users", :action => "edit", :method => :get
map.resource :account, :controller => "users", :except => [:show, :destroy, :edit]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your examples don't even mention IDs, I'd avoid mapping it as a resource altogether, and instead do `map.connect` and specify each route you want manually.

Comment: Well, I'm able to avoid IDs by doing `map.resource` instead of `map.resources`.  I suppose I could switch to `map.connect`, but I guess I'm still curious if there's a way to do this my using `map.resource` ... even if the answer is "No, you can't do that.  Stop trying." :)